# I am getting the error The driver executable does not exist: on system.getproperty

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have written below code and every time I run the code I am getting an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The
>   driver executable does not exist:
>   C:\Users\chromedriver.chromedriver.exe

Please help me figure out what is the reason for this

```
package seleniumsession;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; 

public class launchdriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\chromedriver.chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the file really exists? It seems like the file is missing. Check the path `C:\Users\chromedriver.chromedriver.exe`

Comment: I have checked the chromedriver.exe is present in the file

Comment: It's present _in_ the file?

Comment: my chrome driver version is Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: i have loaded another chrome driver of version 75 ,it was 76 version may be beacuse of that its not working

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe");
  
 WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

Comment: Please edit the question if you need to add stuff. Also it's very unclear what you mean. The Exception clearly states that the executable(file) doesnt exist. Your comments are very confusing and don't answer the question asked. Also the code and comments you've posted lead me to believe the file just doesn't exist. Are you 100% sure that the file with the path you've got in the code, exists and that you have access rights to it?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the file name as "chromedriver.chromedriver.exe" you should use the file name as "chromedriver.exe" under the folder "chromedriver" and create the directory hierarchy as mentioned in the code snippet below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
"C:\\Users\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

What system is doing, it is considering "chromedriver.chromedriver.exe" as ambiguous chrome driver due to which selenium is unable to locate the chrome driver on provided directory.